# How do i make it so my code looks for the minimum amount of coins?

Tags: c++, c

I am on Pset1 of EDX:Computer Science, and im in the end of the "Time for change". 
Here youre supposed to make a code that, once given a number, is supposed to find the least amount of coins you would need. 
I already made my code, but i cant seem to find how to make it so it find minimum. Here is my code:

```
{
    printf ("How much do I owe you?\n");            //Get a non-negative number
    float change =  GetFloat();

    while (change < 0)
    { 
        printf ("Please enter a non-negative number\n");
        change = GetFloat();
    }

    int total = 0;

    while (change >=.25)
    {
        change = change - .25;
        total++;
    }
    while (change >=.1 && change <.25)
    {
        change =  change - .1;
        total++;
    }
    while (change >=.05 && change <.10)
    {
        change = change - .05;
        total++;
    }
    while (change > 0 && change <.05)
    {
        printf ("%i\n", total);
    }
```

When I put in .15, it gives me an answer of 3, but its supposed to say 2.
also, some other things I do do give me a number, but its not minimum.
How can i make it so it always find the minimum amount?

Comment: Be careful for floating-point aritimetic errors. In this case I guess you shouldn't use floating-point values and instead you should use integers.

Comment: (1) Your final `while` loop seems to be messed up.  It should be subtracting .01 and incrementing `total`, but instead it's printing the total.  It may be a paste error, but the `printf` should be outside of the loop.  You can test it with something like 17 cents (2) As MikeCAT mentioned, floating point errors are a problem here.  The best solution is to use pennies rather than dollars, and use integers for your variables.  So 1.00 would become 100.  Then your arithmetic will be exact.

Comment: when you put .15. it processes the two while loops but in last loop the value is not exact 0, it may be like 0.000000001 or something as floating point numbers may have some errors.

Comment: You are trying to track integer amounts of cents but using floating point numbers to do it. That won't work.

Comment: What exactly is the target language? Also, your question lacks the required minimal but complete example, is thus off-topic.

Comment: I run your code in c++ and it gives exactly what you expect, for 0.15 it prints out 2 2 2 2.....

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is *not* use a floating point number to represent currency. Arithmetic operations involving floating points numbers are not precise enough to be used for currency. Change it into an `int`. After that you can use `/` and `%` to compute the number of coins.

```
int amountOwed = ...;      // Amount owed in cents

int total = amountOwed/25; // Number of quarters.
amountOwed = amountOwed % 25; // Amount after the number of quarters.

total += amountOwed/10; // Number of dimes.
amountOwed = amountOwed % 10; // Amount after the number of dimes.

total += amountOwed/5; // Number of nickels.
amountOwed = amountOwed % 5; // Amount after the number of nickels.

// Whatever is left is number of pennies.
total += amountOwed; // Number of pennies.
```

Answer (score 1):

Candidate paths:

1) When comparing `float` values consider the inexactness of representations of values like `0.15` as a `float`.  In the end, fractional of 0.01 need to be addressed.

```
// while (change >=.1 && change <.25)
min_unit = 0.01;
while (change >= (0.10f - min_unit/2)) /* BTW: compare again 0.25 not needed */)
```

2) Convert the return value of `GetFloat()` to whole number of the minimum money unit.

```
min_unit = 0.01;
change = round(GetFloat()/min_unit);

while (change >= 25.0) 
  ....
while (change >= 10.0) 
  ....
```

3) Convert the return value of `GetFloat()` to an integer of the minimum money unit.

```
min_unit = 0.01;
long long Ichange = round(GetFloat()/min_unit);

while (Ichange >= 25 /* min_units */) 
  ....
while (Ichange >= 10 /* min_units */) 
  ....
```

What is best depends on issues not given by OP.  Range of numbers, calculations other than `+,-,*` that needed to be done, compound interest, taxes, etc.

Typically for leaner program, using #3 is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use floating point numbers to track integer numbers of cents. That will never work because floating point is a finite precision representation scheme and not every value you are using can be exactly represented. Use integers.

Here's an analogy to show why that won't work. Imagine if we had coins that represented a third of a dollar and you were using five-digit decimal floating point. That third of a dollar coin would be represented as "0.33333". A dollar, of course is "1.00000". The problem is that when you subtract that one third coin from one dollar three times, you do *not* get zero, you get "0.00001" due to rounding error.

Don't use finite precision schemes to represent values they cannot represent exactly unless you do not need exact results. To specify numbers of coins, you need exact results.